# Increment a number in a PDF

Tags: pdf, tablet, pdf-reader

Is there a way to increment a number in a PDF everytime it is opened/saved? I have a 'mechanic report' PDF which need to be filled with worked hours and what was done and additionally i need this number to be filled in.

Comment: You want to modify values under file propertis -> details?

Comment: More like a label or a counting order number on the report itself.

Comment: Google for "PDF editor". With an editor you can open an PDF file and edit the text in it.

Comment: What should the scope of your number be? The computer the form resides on, or several computers? Is the form used on mobile devices or computers?